# Why does the Front End group backslashes into pairs?

Tags: front-end, syntax

What is `\\` for? Help finds nothing on it. An odd number of backslashes greater than one are grouped by two and the last one is displayed with a different color. This indicates that it should mean something.

There also is a (connected?) little bug in the frontend (Mma 8.0, W7). When a text what is ended by the odd number of backslashes is commented with `Alt`+`/`, pressing the combination again leads not to uncommenting, but to further commenting like this:

```
a\\\
(*a\\\*)
(*(*a\\\*)*)
(*(*(*a\\\*)*)*)
```

etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the tutorial [Special Characters - Strings And Characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialCharacters-StringsAndCharacters.html)

[image]

example

[image]

`Comment/Uncomment` behavior you describe also happens in version 8.0.4.0 on Vista.

Comment: Thanks. Judging from this a combination `\*` is also treated specially (that could prevent Mma from recognizing the ending of the comments `*)`), though it is not mentioned in help.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for the accept. `Un/Comment` function behaves differently depending on the selection. For example, when the selection is cell bracket, `Un/Comment` works as you expect. From the code for the `Un/Comment` function in the file `GetFEKernelInit.tr` in the directory `$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources`, you can see how it treats various selection cases.