# Explicit asterisk or @ sign in string patterns

Tags: string-manipulation

What string pattern will match an explicit asterisk (*) or at-sign (@)? The obvious example, `StringMatchQ["*", "\*"]`, returns `False`. I can't find any mention of escaping them in string patterns, only in `RegularExpressions`, and that was in the advanced tutorial.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22707/string-replacement-of-special-characters and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/why-does-the-front-end-group-backslashes-into-pairs

Answer (score 6):

I thought it worth mentioning that the documentation for `StringMatchQ` gives the following solution to your problem:

> `Verbatim["p"]` specifies the verbatim string `"p"`, with `*` and `@` treated literally.

So you'd be able to do something like:

```
StringMatchQ["*", Verbatim["*"]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: It also mentions `\\*` explicitly in the table directly above that.

Comment: @BrettChampion It's not in the String Patterns tutorial though, which is where I'd have looked.  I didn't put it in my answer because Sjoerd already [covered that pretty well](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25750/explicit-asterisk-or-sign-in-string-patterns/78897?noredirect=1#comment79999_25752).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to escape a `*` character in a string pattern because it's a wildcard.  To escape it, just prepend a backslash to it.  Remember that to insert a backslash in a Mathematica string, you need to type *two* backslashes:

```
StringMatchQ["*", "\\*"]

(* => True *)
```

Comment: Come to think about it, this is pretty deep stuff. In a normal string, an asterisk isn't a special character that needs to be escaped, so `"*"` is just the character with character code 42, and `"\*"` is a single character with code 63432. `"\\*"` equals {92, 42}, and *only because it is used in a string pattern* (where `*` is special) it is interpreted as an escape sequence and equals the literal `"*"` (42). Note that `"*"=="\\*"` yields `False` (whereas `"*"=="*"` yields `True`).

Comment: If you use regexes in shell scripts a lot, you'll get pretty familiar with this type of double (or triple) escaping =)